# How can i find all the items in a List that have the same value and manipulate this items?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

On top of the code:

```
[System.Serializable]
    public class PosDisPair //Name the pair however you like
    {
        public float Distance;
        public Vector3 Pos;
    }
```

Then:

```
private List<PosDisPair> pairList = new List<PosDisPair>();
```

And

```
private void FindDistances()
    {
        pairList = new List<PosDisPair>();

        for (int i = 0; i < objects.Count; i++)
        {
            PosDisPair pairToAdd = new PosDisPair();
            pairToAdd.Distance = Vector3.Distance(EndStartPoints[0].transform.position, objects[i].transform.position);
            pairToAdd.Pos = objects[i].transform.position;
            pairList.Add(pairToAdd);
        }

        pairList.Sort(delegate (PosDisPair a, PosDisPair b) {
            return (a.Distance.CompareTo(b.Distance));
        });

        Manip();
    }
```

And last

```
private void Manip()
    {
        List<float> samedistances = new List<float>();

        pairList = pairList.OrderBy(x => x.Distance).ToList();

        for (int i = 0; i < pairList.Count; i++)
        {
            if (pairList[i].Distance == pairList[i+1].Distance)
            {
                samedistances.Add(pairList[i].Distance);
            }
        }
    }
```

Inside Manip method i'm using OrderBy to sort the List by distances property.
So now the first distance is 0 so i don't need to do with it anything.

Then there are three items that the distance of each one is 10.
But each item position is not the same.

What i want to do is to take out from the List all same distances items each time. For example to take all the 10's distances items thentake from this three items one random item.

Next to pickup random one of two 20's distances items and again each same distances items.

So in the end i will have a List with all items and distances and positions but from each same distances will be only one item.

So in the end in pairList i will have for example:

index 0 = distance 0

index 1 = distance 10

index 2 = distance 14.45456

index 3 = distance 20
.
.
.
index 44 = distance 134

Same distances have each one another position.

For example :

index 1 distance 10, posiiton 1,1,1

index 2 distance 10, position 2,1,1

index 3 distance 10, position 3,1,1

So when it will pick one a random distance 10 it will be with it's own position.

Comment: Its almost as if you have to `GroupBy` a property, and then `Select` a single item...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This will get you the *first* element in each group where you have more than one element.

```
var result = pairList.GroupBy(x => x.Distance).Select(y => y.FirstOrDefault());
```

To get a *random* element, try this:

```
Random rnd = new Random();
var resultRand = pairList.GroupBy(x => x.Distance).Select(y => y.ElementAt(rnd.Next(0, y.Count())));
```

Comment: Grouping by a float number may not be a good idea. For ex `new[] { 1f, Math.Sqrt(2) * Math.Sqrt(1.0/ 2) }.GroupBy(x => x).Count()` returns 2

Comment: @L.B yes I guess that's true, but then again is there _any_ way to compare two floats 100%? Since that's the end goal of  the OP, he/she is going to face that problem whatever is done? Is there a good solution to that?

Comment: It depends on the context of the question(which I don't know) For examle *"close enough"* can be defined by grouping on `(int)(distance * 100)`

Comment: I'm creating a grid of gameobjects and the grid size will be always width same as height. For example 10x10 or 11x11 or 20x20 and i also set the space between the objects for example 10 so it will be equal space between all gameobjects. Maybe this will help to solve the problem ? I didn't add the whole code to my question.

Comment: @DragonFlea my above code sample already solves the problem if `Distance` is of type `int`. But `float` types do not have exact precision and so it's near impossible to do a 100% perfect comparison between two floats. So you need to 'allow' a range and say if a certain two numbers are within a small margin, you take them to be equal.